# how can I put javascript variables in a html action=""

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I want to be able to put my variable in my html action="" so that i can change the search engine I use in one click. instead of having to make another html page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="searchbar">
    <form action="[SEARCH VAR]" method="get">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="q" placeholder=searchvar id="mySearch">
      </form>
    </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="var search=https://www.duckduckgo.com/">
    duckduckgo
  </button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

is there anyway to do it with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have arbitrary HTML attributes be evaluated as JavaScript. Instead you'd use the DOM API to change the `action` property of the form element.

```
function setSearchEngine(engine) {
    document.querySelector('form').action = engine;
}
```

Use as

```
<button type="button" onclick="setSearchEngine('https://www.duckduckgo.com/')">
  duckduckgo
</button>
```